# How to model compound keys (or tuples) in Redis to ease getting one value knowing the other

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I have a key containing an array of IDs like:

```
glid-ids -> 
1 625f15db2ea61be36f694b73
2 625f15db2ea61be36f694b76
3 625f15db2ea61be36f694b78
4 ...
```

But I want to associate each ID with a parent (think of it like a category, knowing a category generally has multiple IDs, but one ID could have few categories too. Like the following (if I had to store tuples, or compound keys like the following):

```
glid-ids -> 
1 625f15db2ea61be36f694b73, gls-20-9
2 625f15db2ea61be36f694b76, gls-10-3
3 625f15db2ea61be36f694b78, gls-20-5
4 ...
5 625f15db2ea61be36f694b73, gls-10-3
```

`625f15db2ea61be36f694b73` parent categories are `gls-20-9` and `gls-10-3`.

The question is how to store this, to later be able to search quickly for all categories (`gls-...`) of a particular ID.

(I am very new to Redis and I'm using [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis), but any hints regardless in JS or not is welcome !)

Comment: Did you check the RediSearch/JSON module? https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/
Notice node-redis has full support for these APIs

Comment: I didn't know about modules at all, then I have to use some wrapper [like](https://impankratov.github.io/ioredisearch/) or run [sendCommand](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/530) apparently. I would stick with basic Redis if possible. I'm impressed how Redis is about data-structures really, like wow, too much for me apparently (coming from SQL and NoSQL).

Comment: thanks for the advice, now I'm checking [redis-om-node](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-node) and it looks so nice

Comment: I'm glad you like Redis OM for Node.js. Makes me a happy coder!

Comment: two Guys x) got confused for a second, thank you both for follow up !